# Installing Windows 7 on a Netbook using a USB harddrive

Tags: windows-7, usb, installation, external-hard-drive

Is there any way that I can use a USB harddrive to install Windows 7 on my Netbook? The Netbook is without a CD-ROM drive.

I've got the Windows 7 installation as an ISO-file, if that helps?

Answer (score 1):

Theres [an app](http://store.microsoft.com/Help/ISO-Tool) for that

Comment: Pretty cool. But my USB HDD is not showing up when I get to the step where I select where to copy the installation files. My USB HDD is formatted: NTFS, logical drive. I've got no device-specific software installed.

Answer (score 0):

sure man... its real easy.. i install windows 7 on netbooks all the time.. first put the ISO file on the desktop of the nettop.. in xp or what ever OS you have on it.. now... use 7-zip www.7-zip.org  (the program is free) use 7-zip to extract the ISO file to a folder.  Now just double click the setup file and go though the process. Windows 7 will install all nessasary files at the first setup.  after it restarts it will have all the files needed so it will not need the installation cd or files because they were already copyed to the Hard drive.  Windows  7 installers are almost fool proof...

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Check our Bootsage, a nice Windows app for building the flash drive under all operating systems XP-Win7.  http://firesage.com/bootsage

Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

I used this for my 16GB USB Drive

http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-install-windows-7vista-from-usb-drive-detailed-100-working-guide/

But Bootsect is found within the ISO so you got to extract it out (Windows doesn't copy that into your computer during installation as its mainly a developer/systems administrator tool)

Might I add that installing form an external HDD or thumbdrive is wayyyy faster than through a DVD.

Oh and Andrew Bolster's link is only for USB thumbdrives. The application detects external hard drives as, well, hard drives.

Answer (score 0):

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb521584(WinEmbedded.51).aspx) on MSDN has some steps to use with DISKPART. See the section, "To prepare a UFD by using DISKPART on Windows Vista"